# Como arrumar a ordem das legendas erradas usando o ggplot2 no R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou tentando gerar um gráfico com estações de monitoramento do IQA de 19 estações. Porém quando eu gero o o grafico a ordem dos grupos ficam erradas, pois ficam assim: **1, 10, 11 , 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,18, 19, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9**.

segue meu código

```
IQA_2005<-quali3%>%
  select(Estacao2, IQA, Ano, Ano2, Epoca)%>%
  filter(Ano2=="2005-01-01")

ggplot(data=IQA_2005, aes(x=as.factor(Estacao2), y=IQA, fill=as.factor(Epoca)))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width=0.7)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#08088A","#9F81F7"))+
  theme_light()+labs(fill="Período Chuvas", title ="Média IQA 2005", x="Estação", y="IQA Médio 2005")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 51, linetype = "51"), colour = "green", size=1.5) +
scale_linetype_manual(name ="IQA BOM", values = c('solid'))
```

Eu tentei usar `as.factor(Estacao2)` porem não obtive êxito

gráfico saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente usar `x = factor(Estacao2, levels = 1:19)` dentro do `aes` do gráfico.

Comment: Obrigado @MarcusNunes era exatamente isso consegui. Ele ficou na ordem correta agora.

Comment: Excelente! Coloquei a resposta abaixo para ficar registrado para dúvidas de outros usuários no futuro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por padrão, o `R` vai entender que caracteres devem ser colocados em ordem alfabética. Neste caso, uma sequência de caracteres de 1 a 19, ao ser ordenada, ficará como abaixo:

```r
x <- as.character(1:19)
sort(x)
#>  [1] "1"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "2"  "3"  "4"  "5" 
#> [16] "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"
```

Uma forma de evitar isso é criando um fator e explicitando seus níveis com o argumento `levels`:

```
factor(x, levels = 1:19)
#>  [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
#> Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Agora basta colocar isso no contexto do gráfico e ele vai sair como deve:

```r
ggplot(data=IQA_2005, aes(x = factor(Estacao2, levels = 1:19), y=IQA, fill=as.factor(Epoca)))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width=0.7)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#08088A","#9F81F7"))+
  theme_light()+labs(fill="Período Chuvas", title ="Média IQA 2005", x="Estação", y="IQA Médio 2005")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 51, linetype = "51"), colour = "green", size=1.5) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name ="IQA BOM", values = c('solid'))
```